# Which are the flags I should use in my linker command line to avoid architecture x86_64 error when using fmt library for c++?

Tags: c++, macos

My linker cmd line is:

```
/usr/local/bin/g++-8 -L/usr/local/lib -lfmt -o "trail2"  ./src/trail2.o
```

My error is:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Which flags am I missing to solve this problem.

Comment: All questions about linker errors always get closed as duplicates. One of the explanations in the linked answer undoubtedly covers your situation, even if it is of no help in solving your problem. Apparently that is good enough to close as a duplicate. Your best bet is probably to search the archives of this site.

Comment: it does with clang++ but not with GNU g++ compiler